# Section not growing dynamically

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Im trying to use css to style my pages. I want the  to grow as the content does. But it seem to be limited to the size of the screen.  I can tell be case the section is a differnt color from its  parent. So some text and other content appears in the body area.

scaffold.css.scss

```
    html
    {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background-color: #C6C0BA;
      color: #636363;
      font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 120%;
      line-height: 18px;
      max-width: 1000px;
      min-height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      }
    section{
        padding: 2%;
          max-width: 1000px;
          background-color: #f3f3f3;
          margin: 0 auto;


  min-height: 100%;
}
.....
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Alpha</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'screen' %>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='logo'>
    <img src="assets/SiteHeader.png" class="stretch">
  </div>
  <header>
    <%= render 'shared/navigation' %>
  </header>

<section id='content'>
  <%= yield %>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ruby on rails, but looking at your CSS, you probably don't want min-height: 100% in either body or #content.  Both should scale automatically to fit their content.  I haven't tested, but if you'd like a minimum height for section (#content), you could try adding one or more fixed-height child elements to it.

e.g:

```
<section id="content">
<div style="height: 768px;">
other stuff here
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: You also may want to lose width and height for HTML{}, as a suggestion.

Comment: If I remove the HTML{} or the body{} definitions the height comes only bout 30px below the header.

Comment: html and body will always match the full size of the window unless you set the size, so far as I know.  e.g. body{background-color: blue;} will give a full page of blue with no other elements added.  Am I wrong?

Comment: well i need to set the width to be a max of 1000px for the body. Not sure if that could cause a problem.